# gesture.ts: child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function

Tags: android, react-native

error node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\src\handlers\gestures\gesture.ts: node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\src\handlers\gestures\gesture.ts: child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function.
TypeError: node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\src\handlers\gestures\gesture.ts: child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function
at \node_modules@babel\plugin-transform-typescript\lib\index.js:361:89
at Array.forEach ()
at PluginPass.Class (node_modules@babel\plugin-transform-typescript\lib\index.js:353:31)
at newFn (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:177:21)
at NodePath._call (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:53:20)
at NodePath.call (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:40:17)
at NodePath.visit (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:100:31)
at TraversalContext.visitQueue (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:103:16)
at TraversalContext.visitSingle (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:77:19)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

In React Native while generate debug apk getting this error, i've run below command. Thanks

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i was trying to generate debug/release apk of my project, when i try to bundle the react native modules it's throwing error, for guesture.ts child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function like this error throwing

Comment: Are you able to figure this our? I am stuck on same thing

Comment: Same problem, any solution for this case?